# woocommerce multiple category products display as sequence of category

Tags: wordpress

I am working in wordpress wocomerce. I have used shortcode to show three different category product. My shortcode is

```
[product_category category="5-days-dinner-package,10-days-dinner-package,15-days-dinner-package" columns="3"]
```

Now I want to show **5-days-dinner-package** category product **first** then **10-days-dinner-package** and **15-days-dinner-package** in sequance.

But here I got output as **5-days-dinner-package** then **15-days-dinner-package** and **10-days-dinner-package**.

So what code should I have to write to resolve this problem?

Comment: can you share screenshot where it is displaying products? because it should display product in short code sequence. Also did you try to put 3 diff. shortcodes for each category products?

Comment: @HelpingHands open this [link](http://www.kitchendeli.com/front/).. open breakfast package where you can see this

Comment: `WP_Query` defaults to post date, though the shortcode should be sorting results by title. Could you check if the products are being arranged by post date?

Comment: I did a test with my own local site and got similar results to you. Maybe contact woocommerce support forum?

Comment: Sort the products by menu order and add arguments `orderby` and `order` in the shortcode.

Comment: @Afaan should I have to write **orderby="title" order="desc"** ?

Comment: yup you can sort it by `date,menu order,title,rand` @Nisarg

Comment: @Afaan Its not working...

Comment: Try with `orderby = "name" order="asc"` @Nisarg